# Приложение не работает

Tags: android, view

Почему вот так работает:

```
    public void onButtonClick (View v){
    EditText el1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Num1);
    EditText el2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Num2);
    TextView resText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Result);
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(el1.getText().toString());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(el2.getText().toString());
    int resSum = num1 + num2;
    resText.setText(Integer.toString(resSum));

}
```

А вот так нет

```
EditText el1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Num1);
EditText el2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Num2);
TextView resText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Result);
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(el1.getText().toString());
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(el2.getText().toString());


public void onButtonClick (View v){


    int resSum = num1 + num2;
    resText.setText(Integer.toString(resSum));

}
```

Где мой гениальный план пошёл не по плану?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `findViewById` ищет View в загруженной ранее размете. Её вы должны загружать в методе `onCreate`. А метод этот, как и любой другой не может быть вызван до полной загрузки класса в JVM. Когда класс загружается в JVM то инициализируются все поля этого класса. Как раз в момент инициализации и вызывается в таком случае метод `findViewById` и пытается найти вьюхи в ещё не загруженной разметке, что, ожидаемо, завершается ошибкой.

Т.е. тут дело в очерёдности выполнения кода.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за пояснения

Answer (score 3):

Редактировал здесь, так что возможны ошибки, но направление примерно такое

Попробуйте так

```
private EditText el1;
private EditText el2;
private TextView resText;
private int num1;
private int num2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        el1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Num1);
        el2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Num2);
        resText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Result);

        public void onButtonClick (View v){
           num1 = Integer.parseInt(el1.getText().toString());
           num2 = Integer.parseInt(el2.getText().toString());

           int resSum = num1 + num2;
           resText.setText(Integer.toString(resSum));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Всё работает, благодарю