# Арифметические операции для калькулятора

Tags: android

Делаю простейший калькулятор, сделал операцию сложения но не могу понять как сделать операции вычитания, деления и умножения.

```
package kz.test.calculator;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    EditText el1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Num1);
    EditText el2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Num2);
    TextView resText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Result);

    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(el1.getText().toString());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(el2.getText().toString());
    int resSum = num1 + num2;
    resText.setText(Integer.toString(resSum));



    }
}
```

Comment: Код в вопросе должен быть размещен форматированным текстом, а не скриншотом

Comment: int resSub = num1 - num2;

Comment: Как же так, сложение сообразил как сделать, а вычитание и умножение нет???

Comment: @Эникейщик думаю не долго [соображал, как ctrl+С нажать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833820/177345), а вот дальше .. не написано

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, можно сделать как-то так:

**MainActivty.java**

```
package kz.test.calculator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText el1, el2;
    TextView resText;
    int num1, num2, res;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        el1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Num1);
        el2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Num2);
        resText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Result);
    };

    public void getValue() {
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(el1.getText().toString());
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(el2.getText().toString());
    };

    public void addition() {
        getValue();
        res = num1 + num2;
        resText.setText(String.valueOf(res));
    };

    public void subtraction() {
        getValue();
        res = num1 - num2;
        resText.setText(String.valueOf(res));
    };

    public void multiplication() {
        getValue();
        res = num1 * num2;
        resText.setText(String.valueOf(res));
    };

    public void division() {
        getValue();
        if (num2 != 0) {
            res = num1 / num2;
            resText.setText(String.valueOf(res));
        } else resText.setText("Нельзя разделить");
    };
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Num1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Число 1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Num2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Число 2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Сложение"
        android:onClick="addition" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Вычитание"
        android:onClick="subtraction" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Умножение"
        android:onClick="multiplication" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Деление"
        android:onClick="division" />

</LinearLayout >
```